# JS redirect/window replace doesn't work if url is the same (but anchor added)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use JS/jQuery to reload the current page and jump to an anchor.

I've tried using:

`window.replace('currentpage/#msg'+.message_id);`

And

`window.location.href ='currentpage/#msg'+.message_id;`

Both change the url in the address but fail to reload the page.

Any other ways to do it?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want the page to reload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call this after changing url :

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

There are more ways to do it: http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html  :)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this way

First get the current URL

```
var CurUrl = window.location;
```

Now change the redirect URL in the browser without further'

```
history.pushState(CurUrl, "OldPage", "NewPage");
```

Now the browser URL has changed but the page was not redirected and get the URL again'

```
var UrlRedirect = window.location;
```

here you can write your code

Finish redirecting

```
window.location = UrlRedirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to force the redirect is to make sure that the URL does change, by adding in a random element. I often add a timestamp to the end of a URL.

This has the added benefit or drawback that each page load will look unique to caching systems/etc. You may or may not want this.